# html cannot see any files when it is outside of root web directory

Tags: php, html, css, web

My html, css, javascript... are in directory /www/ in their own folders /www/html, /www/css, /www/js... The web root is located in /www/www/
Im using the function readfile in my php like so

```
readfile("../html/home.html");
```

to read the html file home but im getting a ton of 404s clientside from the html file ex.

```
<script src="../js/javascript_file.js"></script>
```

would give a 404
**Why is this happening and is there a workaround?**

Comment: it's probably because of the permissions of the folder, You cab change it but it's a security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't navigate upside of the document webroot on clientside.

It's an security feature, which is enabled on Apache Webserver by default.
It shouldn't be possible to access content of `/etc/passwd` (file with user password hashes on UNIX systems) by entering `../../../etc/passwd` in the address bar, for example.

You can try to place the JavaScript and CSS files in another directory.

Alternatively you can try to set the *DocumentRoot* to `/www` and the *DirectoryIndex* to `./www/home.html`. Then it is possible to navigate upside the directory index.

Comment: Yeah makes sense anyway the only reason why i did so was to prevent users from accessing files before they are logged in is there any way to prevent address navigation without affecting php script i tried using htaccess but it prevented html from accessing images/other

Comment: @Patrick There are many methods to give users "protected" files only if they are logged in. One usual way is to print out the file content with an appropiate `content-type`-header in an .php-file. Then you can check the login information first. Another server-side way is to set an htaccess-authentification in front of the directory which contains only the important files.